# spring form:form with no modelAttribute

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am aware of the possibility to build model object by using the code:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="objectModel" action="/fooAction">
    <form:input path="username" value="foovalue"/>
</form:form>
```

given that my model has the "objectModel" object set.

Now, my question is, If I don't have the "objectModel" in my model, is there a way to build a spring mvc form to back a domain model object?

Comment: you could think about using commandName  in form:form

Comment: as far as I have studied, commandName seems to behave similar to modelAttribute, still the objects need to be added to the model from a controller. Here, I need to build an object that has a backing Class, but the object itself is not added to the model.